Hollywood Sci-fFi movie about a police officer getting flashes of past
It is a sci-fi movie. 
There is a police officer who gets flashes of past. The flashes relate to when he or someone else was young. When he is an officer he has some sort of a stone (probably ancient). Also, there is a scene where he has a stone while he is in a taxi and then there is an accident and after the accident he fights with someone bald who seems possessed or something. 
There are centipedes taken out of person's body. People become possessed. Some creatures about the size of small dinosaurs attack people.
At the end of movie, there are centipede drawings and some old person tries to open the door (using the officer's stone and a key that that old person has). Then, at the end, whole police force tries to kill the creatures and centipedes also attack the actress. Actress of the movie look-a-like of Tara Reid.
It's a Hollywood movie and it was released after 2005. It seemed like it was a low budget movie.

Could be Alone in the dark 2005

Edward Carnby (Slater) is a detective who specializes in the occult and other paranormal subjects. He was apparently the subject of strange experiments when he was a child, leaving him with heightened abilities as well as a "sixth sense" that allows him to sense the paranormal. Throughout the film, we also learn that Carnby used to work for Bureau 713, a secret government organization that seeks to protect the world from paranormal dangers.
In his spare time, Carnby investigates the disappearance of the Abkani, an ancient Mayan-like civilization that worshipped demonic creatures from another dimension. Central to the plot are several artifacts un-earthed in 1967 and now on display at the city's Museum of Natural History, at which Carnby's girlfriend Aline (Reid) is the assistant curator. Carnby soon finds himself investigating the very scientist who conducted experiments on him as a child, while working with Aline and former protégé (now rival) Commander Burke, his replacement at Bureau 713, to stop an invasion of the Alien-like demonic creatures who are pouring through a portal opened by the Abkani artifacts.





Thanks. Yes, it is this one.

Glad I could help
